# Flexbox scrolling or stretch does not work properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I've created a website with a flexbox-based structure.  My goal was to have the entire viewable page filled by divs, but to avoid letting any divs push below the lower limit of the browser window.  One of my divs should scroll when the text overflows, but in Firefox it instead affects the entire page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="header_bar">header</div>
<div class="page_grid">
    <div class="pg_nav">nav</div>
    <div class="pg_main">This is the div that should scroll</div>
    <div class="pg_sidebar pg_sidebar2">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header_bar
{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.page_grid
{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.pg_nav
{
    width: 25%;
}

.pg_main
{
    width: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.pg_sidebar
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

Everything works completely fine in Chrome and Safari, but there are problems when I load the website in Firefox.  [I created a pen of the site here](http://codepen.io/daniellevine/pen/MaZgYX).  Does anyone have any advice on how to make this show up the same across all three browsers?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Known bug, Here is the work around. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520

Answer (score 8):

As stated above by [magenetwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665048/flexbox-scrolling-does-not-work-in-firefox/33665182#comment55103416_33665048), this is a known [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520), when I added `min-width:0;min-height:0;` to `.page_grid`, the problem solved.

```
.page_grid
{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /* Firefox bug fix styles */
    min-width:0;
    min-height:0;
    /* End of Firefox bug fix styles */
}
```

Comment: This solved my related problem and should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: In my case the scroll bar was missing, even though there was overflow-y

Comment: I can't believe this bug is still prevalent in Firefox  61 over a year later but this fix worked for me too! +100 thanks! 8-)